# Why are the SigningKeys in TokenValidationParameters always null

Tags: .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to user AddJwtBearer to Authorize my API's.
I'm using this in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers();

AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Issuer:uri"] + Configuration["Issuer:well-known"];
    options.Authority = Configuration["Issuer:uri"];

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Issuer:uri"],
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

But I'm always getting the error : `IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: \nkid: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'` because the `IssuerSigningKeys` are always null inside the `TokenValidationParameters`. Is there a way to load the issuer signing keys from the metadata url provided without writing specific code for that?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the quick reply, but I figured it out. I had 2 issues, 1) I has specifying the `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` endpoint rather then just `.well-known/openid-configuration`, this alone instantiated my ConfigurationManager correctly; 2) I had to add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` and now my code is correctly validating the JWT Bearer token signature against the correct Identity Server.